# how to give imageView tag in objective-c

Tags: ios, xcode

I am developing an App for kids.

```
 images=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Navarre-Family-Eye-Care-Navarre-Florida-Optometrist-Santa-Christmas-Toy-Safety.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"Christmas-Wallpapers-HD-Picture.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"Christmas-Wallpaper-jesus-9413550-1024-768.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"tree.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"luxury-christmas-napkins-father-christmas-1635-p.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"Navarre-Family-Eye-Care-Navarre-Florida-Optometrist-Santa-Christmas-Toy-Safety.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"Christmas-Wallpapers-HD-Picture.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"Christmas-Wallpaper-jesus-9413550-1024-768.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"tree.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"luxury-christmas-napkins-father-christmas-1635-p.jpg"], nil];

    NSString *dd=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", images];
    NSLog(@"%@",dd);



    randomIndex1=arc4random() % images.count;
    selectedImage = [images objectAtIndex:randomIndex1]; //random selected image

    NSLog(@"%@",selectedImage);

    number = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5",@"6",@"7",@"8",@"9",@"10", nil];


    randomNumber = arc4random() % number.count; //random selected number
    NSLog(@"%d",randomNumber);

    for (int i = 0; i <randomNumber; i++)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@", selectedImage);

        // _img.image = selectedImage;

        //cell.img.image=selectedImage;

    }
```

i have used UIView .In UIView i placed 15 ImageViews .As i got the selectedImage from  the output.i need to place the image in ImageView based on tag.how to do

Comment: UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)[self.view viewWithTag:3];
imageView.image=yourimage;

Answer (score 3):

You need to set tag for all 15 images in view like 1,2,3,4,5...15

then check it like

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < randomNumber ; i++){
    id subView = [view viewWithTag:i];

    if ([subView isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]){
        ((UIImageView *)subView).image = selectedImage;
    }

    if ([subView isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]){
       [((UIButton *)subView) setImage:selectedImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}
```

say randomNumber = 5 , then you can set image for your first 5 ImageView.

Comment: ERROR SHOWING AS :Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView setImage:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: @suurabh prajapati,sir can u give same logic ,instead of uiimageview.i need based on uibutton.

Comment: i have set tag for all 9 uibuttons in view like 1,2,......9 then how to apply same logic for uibutton.

Comment: sir,to set the image it should take from dict array how to do

Comment: do you have URL for that image? if YES , then search on google for how to set image on Button from URL. you will get too many answer

Comment: sir,i  am storing the image as "<UIImage: 0x600000099730>, {640, 480}",
    "<UIImage: 0x60800009d740>, {1920, 1200}",
    "<UIImage: 0x60800009d830>, {1024, 768}",
    "<UIImage: 0x60000009d600>, {640, 480}",
    "<UIImage: 0x60000009da10>, {300, 300}",
    "<UIImage: 0x60000009dab0>, {640, 480}",
    "<UIImage: 0x60000009dbf0>, {1920, 1200}",
    "<UIImage: 0x60000009dc90>, {1024, 768}",
    "<UIImage: 0x60000009dd30>, {640, 480}",
    "<UIImage: 0x60000009ddd0>, {300, 300}

Comment: sir      Printing description of self->dict:
<__NSArrayM 0x60800005af40>(
<UIImage: 0x608000095f90>, {640, 480},
<UIImage: 0x600000093ec0>, {300, 300},
<UIImage: 0x600000093d80>, {1024, 768},
<UIImage: 0x6000000941e0>, {1920, 1200},
<UIImage: 0x600000094320>, {640, 480}
)   so this image should set how to do

Comment: Are you storing image in array?Then selectedImage = youArrayOfImage[0] for first image and viceVersa

Comment: for (int p = 0 ; p <dict.count ; p++){
        id subView = [self.view  viewWithTag:p];
        
        if ([subView isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]){
            [( (UIButton *)subView) setImage:colorimage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            colorimage=[dict objectAtIndex:0];
            colorimage=[dict objectAtIndex:1];
            colorimage=[dict objectAtIndex:2];
        
        
        }
    }
i given as this type ,but not working how to do